# Crosstabin Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have DataFrame in Pandas like this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({"price_range": [0,1,2,3,0,2], "blue":[0,0,1,0,1,1], "four_g":[0,0,0,1,0,1]})
```

I have line like this: `pd.crosstab(df['price_range'], df["blue"])`

Nevertheless, now I only see only for example how many "blue" 0 and 1 is for each "price_range", but I want to exapnd this code and also know how many "four_g" 0 and 1 is for each "price_range". How can do that? Please help me

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use 'melt':

```
df_out = df.melt('price_range')

pd.crosstab(df_out['price_range'], df_out['variable'], df_out['value'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Output:

```
variable     blue  four_g
price_range              
0               1       0
1               0       0
2               2       1
3               0       1
```

Another way is to use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('price_range')[['blue','four_g']].sum()
```

Output:

```
             blue  four_g
price_range              
0               1       0
1               0       0
2               2       1
3               0       1
```

Answer (score 0):

a simplest way is using 2 `crosstab` through list comprehension with `concat`

```
cols = ['blue', 'four_g']
df_out = pd.concat([pd.crosstab(df['price_range'], df[col]) 
                            for col in cols], keys=cols, axis=1)

Out[1116]:
            blue    four_g
blue           0  1      0  1
price_range
0              1  1      2  0
1              1  0      1  0
2              0  2      1  1
3              1  0      0  1
```

Comment: does your df have column `price_range` ? I used column name `price_range` due to you used it in your code in the question. Double check if you mistype or have space in the column name